# Problems installing Networkit with pip

Tags: python, linux, networkx, networkit

hi I have tried to install networkit with  `pip install networkit` in Red Hat Enterprise Linux version 8.6 using python 3.6. However, i'm getting an error:  `Building wheel for networkit (setup.py) ... error` . The error is shown as follows:

```
(env) [YEFRY_RUIZ@redhat003 Synopsys_Scripts]$ pip3 install networkit
Collecting networkit
  Using cached networkit-10.0.tar.gz (5.7 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from networkit) (1.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from networkit) (1.19.5)
Building wheels for collected packages: networkit
  **Building wheel for networkit (setup.py) ... error**
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /mnt/vol_NFS_rh003/estudiantes/jeffry
command: /mnt/vol_NFS_rh003/estudiantes/jeffry/Synopsys_Scripts/env/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-pj33rhh3/networkit_23dfc66e17114c61b2e44bea61f5f7ee/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-pj33rhh3/networkit_23dfc66e17114c61b2e44bea61f5f7ee/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-bemnkix4
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-pj33rhh3/networkit_23dfc66e17114c61b2e44bea61f5f7ee/
  Complete output (566 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/GEXFIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/GraphMLIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/algebraic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/coloring.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/csbridge.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/dynamic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/nxadapter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/partitioning.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/plot.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/sampling.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/stopwatch.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/support.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/vizbridges.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/viztasks.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  copying networkit/workflows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit/gephi
copying networkit/test/gephi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit/test/gephi
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit/profiling/html
    copying networkit/profiling/html/measure.html -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit/profiling/html
    copying networkit/profiling/html/overlay.html -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit/profiling/html
    copying networkit/profiling/html/profile.html -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit/profiling/html
    copying networkit/profiling/html/profiling.css -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit/profiling/html
    copying networkit/profiling/html/profiling.js -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit/profiling/html
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit/profiling/latex
    copying networkit/profiling/latex/measure.tex -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit/profiling/latex
    copying networkit/profiling/latex/profile.tex -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit/profiling/latex
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit/profiling/description
    copying networkit/profiling/description/descriptions.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/networkit/profiling/description
    running build_ext
    initializing NetworKit compilation with: 'cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -DNETWORKIT_FLATINSTALL=ON -DNETWORKIT_PYTHON=/usr/include/python3.6m -DNETWORKIT_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/mnt/vol_NFS_rh003/estudiantes/jeffry/Synopsys_Scripts/env/bin/python -DNETWORKIT_PYTHON_SOABI=cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu -DNETWORKIT_PYTHON_VERSION=3.6 /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa'
    -- TLX CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: -Wshadow -Wold-style-cast -std=c++17 -g -W -Wall -Wextra -fPIC  -Wcast-qual -Winit-self -Wnoexcept -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls
    -- sphinx-build not found. Disable documentation targets
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/build/build_python
    Build with: 'make install -j16'
    Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target tlx
    [ 12%] Built target tlx
    Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target networkit
    [ 86%] Built target networkit
    [ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/generators.dir/networkit/generators.cpp.o
    [ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/base.dir/networkit/base.cpp.o
    [ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/helpers.dir/networkit/helpers.cpp.o
    [ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/clique.dir/networkit/clique.cpp.o
    [ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/globals.dir/networkit/globals.cpp.o
    [ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/embedding.dir/networkit/embedding.cpp.o
    [ 89%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dynamics.dir/networkit/dynamics.cpp.o
    [ 89%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/flow.dir/networkit/flow.cpp.o
    [ 89%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/stats.dir/networkit/stats.cpp.o
    [ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/graph.dir/networkit/graph.cpp.o
    [ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/distance.dir/networkit/distance.cpp.o
    [ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/correlation.dir/networkit/correlation.cpp.o
    [ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/engineering.dir/networkit/engineering.cpp.o
    [ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/components.dir/networkit/components.cpp.o
    [ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/linkprediction.dir/networkit/linkprediction.cpp.o
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/base.cpp:20:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/globals.cpp:25:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/base.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/base.dir/networkit/base.cpp.o] Error 1
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/embedding.cpp:25:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1463: CMakeFiles/base.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/clique.cpp:26:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/stats.cpp:25:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/generators.cpp:25:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/globals.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/globals.dir/networkit/globals.cpp.o] Error 1
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/flow.cpp:25:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1220: CMakeFiles/globals.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/clique.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/clique.dir/networkit/clique.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1597: CMakeFiles/clique.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/generators.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/generators.dir/networkit/generators.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/flow.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/flow.dir/networkit/flow.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/embedding.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/embedding.dir/networkit/embedding.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1516: CMakeFiles/generators.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1409: CMakeFiles/embedding.dir/all] Error 2
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/engineering.cpp:25:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1274: CMakeFiles/flow.dir/all] Error 2
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/dynamics.cpp:25:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/helpers.cpp:26:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/correlation.cpp:25:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/engineering.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/engineering.dir/networkit/engineering.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1301: CMakeFiles/engineering.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dynamics.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/dynamics.dir/networkit/dynamics.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/helpers.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/helpers.dir/networkit/helpers.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1355: CMakeFiles/dynamics.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1570: CMakeFiles/helpers.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/stats.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/stats.dir/networkit/stats.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/correlation.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/correlation.dir/networkit/correlation.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1543: CMakeFiles/stats.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1382: CMakeFiles/correlation.dir/all] Error 2
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/linkprediction.cpp:26:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/components.cpp:25:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    [ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/coarsening.dir/networkit/coarsening.cpp.o
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/linkprediction.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/linkprediction.dir/networkit/linkprediction.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/components.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/components.dir/networkit/components.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1624: CMakeFiles/linkprediction.dir/all] Error 2
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/distance.cpp:26:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1436: CMakeFiles/components.dir/all] Error 2
    compilation terminated.
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/graph.cpp:26:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/distance.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/distance.dir/networkit/distance.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/graph.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/graph.dir/networkit/graph.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1247: CMakeFiles/distance.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1328: CMakeFiles/graph.dir/all] Error 2
    /tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/networkit/coarsening.cpp:25:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/coarsening.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/coarsening.dir/networkit/coarsening.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1651: CMakeFiles/coarsening.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
    Build tool returned an error, exiting setup.py
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /mnt/vol_NFS_rh003/estudiantes/jeffry/Synopsys_Scripts/env/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bkz0biq2/networkit_203a223c4e3a4c1c9cb98771ad963dfa/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-4jw8w_v9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /mnt/vol_NFS_rh003/estudiantes/jeffry/Synopsys_Scripts/env/include/site/python3.6/networkit Check the logs for full command output.
```

I would appreciate some help. That's the error it's currently happen when i try to install networkit, most of it(a word quantity limit allowed). I already have cython installed.

Comment: "*Building wheel for <package_name> (setup.py) ... error*" is the generic error message when pip fails to build a package. Are there no other error messages or info on why the build failed? The error message you posted is clipped, but there might be more info down the log.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi. I updated the question as clearly as i could due to a maximum number of words allowed